# Pulling microarray data by MNI coordinates

Tags: allen-sdk

How can I write a query in `RESTful` to get human micro-array data by `MNI` coordinate?

I would like to pull a `CSV` of all the microarray measured gene expression levels within a volume of MNI space.  Or by structure but with the `MNI` coordinate each micro array sample came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are provided in the zipped spreadsheets you can download here:

http://human.brain-map.org/static/download

There are `mni_x`, `mni_y`, and `mni_z` columns in the samples spreadsheet.

Via RMA, you can download the T1->MNI affine transform for a given a donor (e.g. name H0351.2001, id 9861) as follows:

`http://api.brain-map.org/api/v2/data/Specimen/query.xml?criteria=[name$eq'H0351.2001']&include=alignment3d`

The return can be reshaped into a matrix like this (MATLAB syntax):

```
M = [ x.tvr_00 x.tvr_01 x.tvr_02 x.tvr_09;
      x.tvr_03 x.tvr_04 x.tvr_05 x.tvr_10;
      x.tvr_06 x.tvr_07 x.tvr_08 x.tvr_11 ];
```

Then you can take a sample's T1 XYZ coordinates, premultiply with that matrix, and you have coarse MNI coordinates.